# Underscore treats val like a def

Tags: scala, lambda

I think I understand why this happens

```
def x() = 1
x _   // () => Int
x() _ // error: _ must follow method; cannot follow Int
```

`x _` turns the method into a function, so you get a no-arg function. `x() _` makes no sense because calling the method gives you an Int, which can't be turned into a function. But then why does this happen?

```
val x = 1
x _   // () => Int
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is little difference between a `val` and a parameterless method, except that the parameterless method doesn't calculate the value until it's called (and will re-calculate the value for each additional call). What really happens to a `val` underneath is that there is a private field declared along with a public accessor method that returns that value.

```
object Test {
    def method = 1
    val value = 1
}
```

Compiles to:

```
object Test extends Object {
  def method(): Int = 1;
  private[this] val value: Int = _;
  <stable> <accessor> def value(): Int = Test.this.value;
  def <init>(): Test.type = {
    Test.super.<init>();
    Test.this.value = 1;
    ()
  }
}
```

Note the line:

```
 <stable> <accessor> def value(): Int = Test.this.value;
```

This allows you to, for example, override a `def` in a super-class with a `val` in a sub-class, since it's *actually* overriding a method. Since a method is actually generated, you are allowed to eta-expand a `val` into a function.

Comment: *There is little difference between a val and a parameterless method, except that the parameterless method doesn't calculate the value until it's called.* Also, the parameterless method will compute the result every time it's called.